# Questions regarding my network plan

Tags: networking, routing, vlan, subnet

I'm developing an IT infrastructure room for testing purposes.
The overall aim is to create a network, which if fully disconnected from the productive environment and several people can come and "book" a rack for their own testing.

There are some requirements, which I have to complete. I'm attaching the network plan to this post, because maybe it's not that easy to understand.

- Firewall with content filtering
- There are several racks, which are "bookable" and the customers can come and test their whole things out. So the most of the networks should not be able to communicate with each other. Just with the internet connection. On the picture each router 1-6 symbolizes a rack (some of them are not that big)
- Each group should have its own switch to connect new things to it. Maybe a router (optional)
- 1 DMZ network
- New groups should be addable to the master switch (if there are new one's to connect)
- I'm not allowed to use a level 3 switch with VLAN, because it's to expensive and when each person has its own (switch/router), they can configure more for themselves

Communication:

- The DMZ should only communicate with the ADSL
- LAN 1 - 5 should only communicate with the ADSL and the LAN 6
- LAN 6 should communicate with the ADSL and the LAN 1-5

[**-->Network plan**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpnDn.png)

Now I have a few questions:

- Is this network as it is realizable? (Communication etc...)
- Is RIP (Routing Information Protocol) a thing, that I have to look at? (router to router)
- The Cisco 8971W router (Master) hast an 8 port switch. Can I use one of them to create an DMZ? Or do I need an additional router ([Router Details](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/860-880-890/hardware/installation/guide/1Overview880-860.html#wp1250888))

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this network as it is realizable? (Communication etc...)

Yes, though I have some doubts about the equipment you picked. Looks like that Linksys crap Cisco acquired years ago. If it is, it's capabilities are "limited", and you're likely to run into "issues".

> Is RIP (Routing Information Protocol) a thing, that I have to look at? (router to router)

You're network is so simple I'd just setup the static route and call it a day. RIP certainly works too, but if you're not familiar with it the static route is going to take up less of your time.

> The Cisco 8971W router (Master) hast an 8 port switch. Can I use one of them to create an DMZ?

I *think* that's a "no", but I'm not familiar with that particular device line.

---

You seem like you're in over your head. I think you'd be much better off hiring a consultant who already knows how to setup isolated networks to help you design this one. Server Fault is not intended to be a protracted design advice site, which is where this question is heading. If you have questions about the suitability of particular products to meet your requirements you should direct those at your sales rep.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not allowed to use a level 3 switch with VLAN, because it's to
>   expensive and when each person has its own (switch/router), they can
>   configure more for themselves

This is the part that I see getting you into the most trouble.  In essence your entire post is "I want to create my own private ISP", with each client having their own networking capabilities that without proper segmentation and ACL restrictions will cause you heartache.

Your 3 communication bullet points make it even more complex because once you allow each client to inject their own switch/router there's no guarantee that they won't break one of those bullet points you mentioned.

IMO, I agree with ChrisS and think you should consult with someone and test, test, test.  Set up what you think will work and see if it does for you.  It's too difficult for us to look at a network topology and say "I like that idea"...if you have an actual break/fix question during/after deployment that's another thing and potentially valid here.